# When you disconnect the headphones from the computer, the sound disappears in the game on monogame. How to fix this?

Tags: c#, monogame

Is there any way to detect that the audio output device has been disconnected/connected? If so, how do I manually change the device when it is disconnected/connected? I found similar problems with OpenGL and monogame on the Internet, but could not find a normal solution

Comment: OpenGL doesn't provide any means to play sound, so it's probably a pure monogame problem

Comment: So there is no way to fix it?